# Refresh edit box after information change

Tags: xpages

I have edit box which has validation- it is required field and it has range of values validation as well. The validation works ok, but the problem is that error message does not dissapear when I replace the values in edit box with valid ones. I tried to add full update on onchange event but this is not a option for me since this changes other fields in my xpage as well. The partial update on the field does not work. Any advice how to refresh the field so that error message dissapears?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a wrapper panel or div around BOTH the field and the error message control and set it's ID to the one that should be partially refreshed. I assume you use

```
XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:idOfYourField}")
```

in the onblur client event!? So just change the ID name here.

Comment: no I just clicked the Partial update radiobutton in server options and selected the element I need to update. I'll try your solution and will post the results, thanks for the answer.